# Is there a way to wait for a window to close, with TestCafe

Tags: javascript, testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I have a set of automated tests which open a child window + click a button to close the child window, which then causes a page navigation. Asserting the URL results in `Failed to restore connection to window within the allocated timeout.`

```js
// In child window
await t.typeText(<field>, 'text').click(<submitButton>);

// Main window
await t.expect(getCurrentUrl()).contains('thank_you')
```

My assumption here is that TestCafe still believes it is in the child window, without waiting for the window to close, and subsequent page navigation.

I can add in some validation, to ensure we're back on the main window... but I was wondering if there was an inbuilt solution to this problem? (I couldn't see anything in the docs).

Answer (score 1):

After closing the child window, execute the following command:

```js
await t.switchToMainWindow();
```

Comment: Sadly that doesn't make a difference, I also tried `await t.switchToParentWindow();` but the same error is presented. I've raised a bug with TestCafe, to see if it can be reproduced. https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/6038

Comment: I researched your case, and it turns out that it is more complicated than I thought. This behavior looks like a bug. Thanks for the report.